# Best way to disable ordering for a particular tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBarController setup and everything is working as intended.  However, I also have enough items to allow for a "More" tab to display.

When I "Edit" the items, I can replace all 4 tab items, but, but I'd like to make the first item not rearrangeable or replaceable. Like the "More" tab item is -- leaving only 3 items editable.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`customizableViewControllers`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621184-customizableviewcontrollers) to an array of view controllers that does not include the first view controller.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  This would be a bit cleaner if I created the views programmatically... but given I used storyboard, is there a way to programmatically access the list of Storyboard linked viewcontrollers?

Comment: Yes, they are the tab bar controller's `viewControllers`.